# Problems with SQL and Python to extract values

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem when i extract values from a DB with `sqlite3`. Everytime that i extract values ,for example, one number have this format:

```
[(6,)]
```

And is like tuple.
I want only the 6 value WITHOUT   `,` and `(` and `[`

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: what about `x = [(6,)]` and `x[0][0]` ?

Comment: What statements have you tried?

Comment: This is common in scenerio when adapter do not know either number of rows or number of columns to output. I am pretty sure it return a value when we fetch max() of the column in which it knows that there will be only value to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common in all SQL adapters.  They always return a list of rows (tuples) even if you only fetchone, it comes back with a tuple, because it doesn't know if this is one value, or one row of values, so to stay constant... tuple.

x[0] is your first row
x[0][0] is your first item in that row.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all people. An special to eatmeimadinish for the clear explanation.